# Should we merge tag "bed" and "build-plate"?

Tags: discussion, tags

As the question states, should [bed](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bed) and [build-plate](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/build-plate) be merged? Basically, both tags refer to the same part of the printer; [bed](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bed) should be a synonym for [build-plate](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/build-plate).

Comment: For discussions: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/103247/should-we-merge-tag-bed-and-build-plate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should not be about merging of tags, rather we should come up with a proper terminology to identify the correct parts of the "build platform".

Basically, every printer consists of a frame with some sort of guide rails<sup>1</sup> moving a carriage. On this carriage a build surface is attached where the printer prints the print on; it is always the top of the stack. Note that this can be e.g. a moving Y-axis<sup>2</sup> or moving Z-axis carriage<sup>3</sup>. In some cases the carriage is missing and there is just a static mounting, then it's a platform instead<sup>4</sup>. It is basically irrelevant if the build surface is glued to the stack or removeable in some way or another.

Between the carriage and the build surface you can have have a stack of multiple elements: a structure or structures, a plate, plates or matts, insulation, etc. This **whole** assembly of elements make up the build platform, an example is shown below.

[image: Proposed build platform terminology]

Note that the linear support can be mounted in Y or Z direction. To tag the elements that make up the *build platform assembly*, a proposed solution can consist of the following terms for subassemblies:

- [z-axis](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/z-axis) or [y-axis](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/y-axis) in combination with [carriage](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/carriage),
- [platform](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/platform) (to support printers that have a solid platform, e.g. Hyrel/Delta)
- [heated-bed](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/heated-bed) (aluminium bed or a silicone matt), which can have a
- [glass-print-surface](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/glass-print-surface), [pei-print-surface](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pei-print-surface), [buildtak-print-surface](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/buildtak-print-surface), etc. possibly augmented with the additional tag of [removeable-print-surface](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/removeable-print-surface) or [magnetic-print-surface](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/magnetic-print-surface).

### Annotations

1. The rails often take the shape of rods and bearings, linear rails
   of V-slot profile.
2. Carthesian Portal or Cantilever printers
3. CoreXY like the Hypercube
4. Delta Printers

Answer (score 1):

## Edit: I like Trish's suggestion best.

I vote **no**. Our (Hyrel) printers have, on some models, a thick aluminum [bed](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bed) that can reach 200C, but we expect users to mount different [build-plate](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/build-plate)s on it, depending on what material they're printing with. These can be coated with PEI, garolite, polycarbonate, or others; or they can be commercial build plates like GeckoTek or Anycubic Ultrabase.

You heat the bed. You print on the build plate. In some cases, these may be a single item.

Comment: Fair enough, but I think all of the current bed-tag questions fall in the build-plate category, so bed tags could be removed and questions retagged untill we get a Hyrell bed question. What I mean to say is that currently all bed questions are tagged incorrectly. I will go through them to find out. Thanks for the feedback!

Comment: Note for a heated bed there is a separate tag!

Comment: Hmm. Well, I suppose there's no need for an unheated beds tag... We actually have a chilled (sub-zero) bed as well, but no need to go making a bunch of tags just to satisfy ontological OCD. :)

Comment: :-) That was exactly my point, the bed can be merged to build-plate. Then you still have the option to not add the heated-bed tag, then it does not have to be heated.

Comment: or we separate better: Bed for the mechanical side, heated-bed for the heating, build-plate for adhesion or surface things?

Comment: @Davo see https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/103247/should-we-merge-tag-bed-and-build-plate

Comment: @Tris thanks, I've added some info there.

Answer (score 1):

I too vote for **no**, but for different reasons:

The [y-axis](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/y-axis) or [z-axis](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/z-axis) hold the [carriage](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/carriage), which levels the Print[bed](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bed). The [bed](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bed) can be heated and is the carrier for the [build-surface](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/build-surface). For example, whenever we talk about a "glass bed" we actually mean a glass [build-plate](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/build-plate) that is mounted on a heated bed. Springsteel usually is correctly referred to as build surface. BuildTak and other build-surfaces are bonding directly to the bed. The distinction is pretty much along these lines:

- The mechanical moving system is under the [bed](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bed)

  - the heating effect of this makes it a [heated-bed](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/heated-bed)
- The area directly in contact with the extruded plastic is the [build-surface](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/build-surface)
- The plate in contact with the curing resin in an SLA printer would be the [build-surface](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/build-surface)

Technically, there might be a renaming needed closely related:

- [glass-bed](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/glass-bed) to [glass-build-surface](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/glass-build-surface)?

Comment: We need to come up wit a good terminology, all `bed` tagged questions are in fact not related to the bed structure, but to the `heated bed` or the `print surface/volume`. I find `bed` to be difficult to use correctly, certainly for newcomers, `platform` or `bed-structure`, `heated-bed-plate`, `glass-print-surface`, `PEI-print-surface`, etc. are more logical. So if the `bed` questions are re-tagged correctly, we won't have a `bed` tag left!

Comment: That... actually seems like a good solution. @Davo what do you think? Kill `bed` and `build-plate` completely in a rebranding and sort the questions into `bed-movement`/`bed-structure` and `bed-heating`/`heated-bed` and `build-surface`/`glass-build-surface`/`removeable-build-surface`?

Comment: see also: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/103247/should-we-merge-tag-bed-and-build-plate

Comment: I've posted in the chat.

Comment: This sounds great.